# What's the equivalent of Obj.C's NSMutableDictionary<Class, Class> in Swift?

Tags: swift

What's the equivalent of Obj.C's `NSMutableDictionary<Class, Class>` in Swift?

I tried:

```
var dictionary = [AnyClass: AnyClass]()
```

However this throws the error: `Type 'AnyClass' (aka 'AnyObject.Type') does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'`

Since there can only be one class per name, we know a given class reference refers to a unique class; there is only one "String" in a given namespace. So why is this not hashable?

I also tried:

```
var dictionary = NSMutableDictionary<AnyClass, AnyClass>
```

However this also fails with: `Cannot specialize non-generic type 'NSMutableDictionary'`

I thought Swift was supposed to be type-safe, but here the compiler is encouraging me to just throw anything into this NSMutableDictionary without type-checking it to make sure it's an AnyClass!

Also, DO NOT lecture me about "You shouldn't be doing that in the first place," because, *I am not doing it*, it's already like that in some Objective C code that I am required to translate into Swift. I am simply trying to do it in the best possible way—if it means I must resort to a non-type-safe NSMutableDictionary, then so be it, however this seems ridiculous.

Surely I'm missing something here... what am I missing?

Comment: If you edit your question and show what type of objects you are trying to add to your dictionary it would be easier to help you solving your problem. You are probably looking for is `var dictionary: [AnyHashable: AnyObject] = [:]` but I still think there is probably a better approach other than using AnyHashable type for your dictionary keys.

Comment: “We know a given class reference refers to a unique class ... So why is this not hashable?” Just because any given class is distinct from another (if that’s what you’re saying) doesn’t mean that either class is hashable. Being hashable means that every *instance* of that type produces a numerical hash value, and `AnyClass`, alone, offers no such assurances.

Comment: @Rob Well, personally, I don't like the fact that metatypes in Swift are these weird special things that can't be dealt with in a normal way like they could in Objective C. It's getting better though and things like introspection and keypaths being able to reference the type via self are awfully nice. Anyway I figured out a solution that works great, see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can get in Swift, I discovered, is to do this:

```
var classToClassMapping = Dictionary<ObjectIdentifier, AnyClass>()

extension Dictionary where Key == ObjectIdentifier, Value == AnyClass {
    subscript<T>(keyType: T.Type) -> AnyClass? {
        get {
            let id = ObjectIdentifier(keyType)
            return self[id]
        }
        set {
            let id = ObjectIdentifier(keyType)
            self[id] = newValue
        }
    }
}

classToClassMapping[Yay.self] = NSString.self

if let stringClass = classToClassMapping[Yay.self] as? NSString.Type {

    print(stringClass.init(string: "hell yeah"))

}

// Prints "hell yeah"


// Alternative:

switch classToClassMapping[Yay.self] {
case let val as NSString.Type:
    print(val.init(string: "yaiirrr boy"))
default:
    print("woops")
}

// prints "yaiirrr boy"
```

Works perfectly for my needs! (Using Swift 5.1 here)